# database locked error

Tags: iphone

iam getting database locked error .

```
-(IBAction)YesData:(id)sender
 {
 [self Check_Create_DB];

sqlite3 *database;



if(idimg == 0)
{

 NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image);  

UIImage *dataImage=[[UIImage alloc] init];

 dataImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];  

    int ycount1=1;

int ncount1=0;

int neutcount1=0;  

if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)

{
    NSLog(@"Connection Open");  

   const char *sqlTmp="insert into 

    images(imgname,ycount,ncount,neutcount)values(?,?,?,?)";


    sqlite3_stmt *cmp_sqlstmt;

    int returnvalue=sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlTmp,-1,&cmp_sqlstmt,NULL );

    if(returnvalue ==  SQLITE_OK)
    {      
      sqlite3_bind_blob(cmp_sqlstmt, 1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);

        sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt, 2, ycount1);


        sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt, 3, ncount1);

        sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt, 4, neutcount1); 

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlstmt))
                               NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        NSLog(@"insert successfully") ;              

    }
    sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlstmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(cmp_sqlstmt);

   sqlite3_close(database);





    lblvote.text=@"You Voted Yes";

     [newView setHidden:NO];
  }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(database); 
   }


  }
   else
  {
   // [self Check_Create_DB];
    //sqlite3 *database;

    sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String],&database);

    if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@"Connection Open");

        idycount+=1;

         const char  *sqlTmp="update Images set ycount=? where imgid= ?";  


        sqlite3_stmt *cmp_sqlstmt;


        int returnvalue=sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlTmp,-1,&cmp_sqlstmt,NULL);


        NSLog(@"return value.....%d",returnvalue);


        if(returnvalue == SQLITE_OK)

        {  

          sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt,1,idycount );


             sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt,2,idimg );


            NSLog(@"updated");

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlstmt))

                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


            sqlite3_reset(cmp_sqlstmt);     


        }
        else
        {

            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


        }

        sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlstmt);


        sqlite3_finalize(cmp_sqlstmt);


        sqlite3_close(database);



    }
    else
    {

    sqlite3_close(database);


    }


  }
}
```

Comment: this is the error:'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while updating. 'database is locked''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f5b5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00d8a313 objc_exception_throw + 44
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f13ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you havent closed the database properly (sqlite3_close(database)). This could have happened before your implementation looked like above where you close the db properly.Try to reinstall the the db and tables

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic:

For future project take a look at [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

> FMDatabase is an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite